# How can I disable the Rainblower's Pyrovision effects?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

I've recently purchased a Collector's Professional Killstreak Rainblower but I am unable to see the effect due to Pyrovision being active.

Is there any way to disable Pyrovsion effects but still see the eye effect?

Answer (score 1):

[This Steam forum thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2776970) could help you out a bit. Basically, what you're doing is creating a replacement for the mtp.cfg file found within the vtf files. I do believe since it's a few years old you might need to do a couple things differently. You don't need to use GCFScape at all, for one, and you just want to look at the following:

```
Put mtp.cfg file here:
(NOT in gcfscape, but in your steamapps folder.)

Steamapps/"USERNAME"/Team Fortress 2/tf/cfg
```

I can't test this right now, but I believe what you want to do instead is go inside the /tf/custom folder and create a folder named whatever you want, "Pyrovision Fix", maybe. Inside that, create a folder named "cfg" and put the mtp.cfg file there, rather than directly in /tf/cfg.

To disable pyrovision in all maps, I'm thinking that you'd just want to leave the mtp.cfg practically blank, like:

```
"VisionFilterShadersMapWhiteList"
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. There unfortunately, is no way to do so.